# The same protobuf message field name for various types

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to set up a `protobuf` protocol to match with a `json` schema. The `json` schema is built up of a few objects that are referenced by each other. One of the objects `PV` has a property `value` which, according to the schema, can either be a string, a boolean or another object, `S`. I've problem how this should be defined in the `protobuf` schema while preserving the name `value`.  The problem is parsing `json` files, that follow the `json` schema, via `protobuf` to Python objects.

I've tried

```
message PV{
    oneof value{
        string stringValue=3;
        bool boolValue=4;
        S sValue=5;
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

`Message type "PV" has no field named "value"`

when trying to parse a `json` file that follows the `json` schema via `protobuf` to a Python object.

I've also tried:

```
message PV{
    google.protobuf.Any value=2;

}
```

with no success.

The question is: Is it possible to twist `protobuf` into keeping the field name of a message, value in my case, but let it be a variaty of types including other Messages?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using

```
message PV{
    google.protobuf.Value value=2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the python generated code: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#oneof

The oneof name ("value" in your case) is not generated into any field. In your case `google.protobuf.Value` might well be the right solution.